# com.google.android.maps.MapView, was not found in the project or the libraries

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I've been on this problem for several days now, not getting any wiser.

In main.xml I get an error saying:
"Class referenced in the layout file, com.google.android.maps.MapView,
was not found in the project or the libraries"

This really puzzle me, as I see MapView.class in Google APIs [Android 2.3.3]
maps.jar

Any ideas towards resolving this issue? This really bugs me I can't find
a solution on my own.

My API key is Ver. 2

I'm using Eclipse - Android Developer Tools Build: v22.0.0-675183

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="AIzaSyCSeU48SfPfRRuA-3YycsVxd_s9MFV8g3M"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tit.GPSLocator"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="10"
android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true" />

<permission
android:name="com.tit.GPSLocator.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission  android:name="com.tit.GPSLocator.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:allowBackup="true">

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity android:name="com.tit.GPSLocator.GPSLocatorActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCSeU48SfPfRRuA-3YycsVxd_s9MFV8g3M" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: have you tried cleaning the project?

Comment: Oh yes. Quite a few times. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Ok, after moving API key <meta-data> inside <activity>, I cleaned the project again, and I could run the application. I get the grid on the map, but no map-tiles: "java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3" but thst's a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you should not be using `com.google.android.maps.MapView` in the first place. That is for the deprecated Maps V1 API. Everything else you are doing -- notably, your API key -- is from [the Maps V2 API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/).

Comment: Yes, I saw something about MapView being deprecated, but then i found this: [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView) and there is no mentioning of deprecated. Anyway, I don't think this has to do with API version, because I see MapView.class in Google APIs [Android 2.3.3] maps.jar, so it's in there.

Comment: @MogensBurapa: "Yes, I saw something about MapView being deprecated, but then i found this: link and there is no mentioning of deprecated" -- that is not the class that you are using. That page is for the Maps V2 `MapView`, which is `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView`. You are not using that. You are using `com.google.android.maps.MapView`, which is the Maps V1 `MapView`. Do not mix and match Maps V1 with Maps V2.

Comment: But still. MapView.class is in there, and should be recognized by Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after moving `meta-data  API key` inside `activity`, I cleaned the project again, and I could run the application. I get the grid on the map, but no map-tiles: `java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3` but that's a different problem.